# Deny SVN Path Authentication, Harry Sally example not working

Tags: svn, path, authz

I'm trying to deny svn permission on a subfolder as per svnbook example

```
[calc:/branches/calc/bug-142]
harry = rw
sally = r

[calc:/branches/calc/bug-142/secret]
harry =
```

So harry don't get access to secret folder. In my case, svn://repos/secret

```
[/]
* = r
robin = rw

[secret]
robin =
```

robin still able to access secret. I tried all forms [/secret], [repos:/secret], [respos/secret:/], but none worked.

Using svn 1.7.2 windows

Comment: Is secret a repo or folder inside repo?

Comment: in this case [repos:/secret], there **secret is folder inside repo repos**

Comment: that is the problem, it doesn't work. I have tried different versions [repos/secret:/], [repos:/secret]

Answer (score 0):

If you use local file:// repository, not `svnserve` neither `passwd`, nor `authz` work.